# What's the character in the poster hanging on the wall supposed to be?

Tags: urusei-yatsura

In the beginning of **Urusei Yatsura - Beautiful Dreamer**, the class is setting up their classroom to be the *"Third Reich Decadent Coffee Shop"*, and in a panning shot of the classroom, there's a poster of a red guy that is obviously supposed to be dressed up as Adolf Hitler. But what's the character supposed to be? Is it a reference to some bit of popular culture or from another show?

[image]